# WinUI3 Cannot locate resource from 'ms-appx:///FooLibrary/Themes/Foo.xaml'. [Line: X Position: Y]

Tags: uwp, winui-3

I have a source library `HtSuite.WinUI.UI` which is deployed as a nuget package. Inside of this project are some `ResourceDictionary`.
Now I made a new project, added my nuget package and wanted to link the `ResourceDictionary` in the `App.xaml`.

Unfortunately, I then get the following error message and cannot build the project.
Is there a trick to integrate external resources?

###### NuGet Package Project: HtSuite.WinUI.UI *.csproj

```xml
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows10.0.18362.0</TargetFramework>
    <TargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0.18362.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
    <RootNamespace>Haprotec.WinUI.UI</RootNamespace>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-x86;win10-x64;win10-arm64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
    <UseWinUI>true</UseWinUI>
    <WindowsPackageType>None</WindowsPackageType>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <!--https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/5886-->
    <WinUISDKReferences>false</WinUISDKReferences>
    <EnablePreviewMsixTooling>true</EnablePreviewMsixTooling>
    <GenerateLibraryLayout>true</GenerateLibraryLayout>
    <AllowUnsafeBlocks>true</AllowUnsafeBlocks>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

[image]

###### T2020.UI Application with error message

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I commented out the following flags, it now works as usual.
Among other things, these were leftovers from the beginnings of WinUI and were "forgotten" in the course of development or seem to highlight such problems.

```xml
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows10.0.18362.0</TargetFramework>
    <TargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0.18362.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
    <RootNamespace>Haprotec.WinUI.UI</RootNamespace>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-x86;win10-x64;win10-arm64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
    <UseWinUI>true</UseWinUI>
    <!--<WindowsPackageType>None</WindowsPackageType>-->
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <!--https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/5886-->
    <!--<WinUISDKReferences>false</WinUISDKReferences>-->
    <!--<EnablePreviewMsixTooling>true</EnablePreviewMsixTooling>-->
    <!--<GenerateLibraryLayout>true</GenerateLibraryLayout>-->
    <!--<AllowUnsafeBlocks>true</AllowUnsafeBlocks>-->
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is related to this [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/6299) in the WinUI GitHub repo.

This [workaround](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/6299#issuecomment-1023856405) might help.

ms-appx:///C:/Program Files/...[Package Location]/HTSuit.WinUI.UI/Themes/CorporateDesign.xaml

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Although I can now build the project, I get 'XAML Parse Exceptions' because it cannot find the resources. In addition, it is impossible for me to deliver the software to the customer (if my user account is stored in the source path) 

Comment: That is a big problem...Weird that templated custom controls can be found in a NuGet package and a simple resources can't...